# Inicio de sesión con Google usando firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-auth, google-signin

Estoy realizando una autenticación con el paquete google_sign_in en flutter y ya tengo configurado todo lo necesario en la consola de firebase que va desde registrar mi app, google_services.json, agregar las claves sha1 y sha256 en la configuración del proyecto y habilitar la autenticación por Google. El problema es que cuando estoy probando la app al darle iniciar sesión me abre el pop up de Google que me muestra seleccionar que cuenta quiero usar y cuando la selecciono esta se cierra y no hace nada.

Esta es mi vista principal el cual checa si ya esta iniciado sesión atreves de un streambuilder y si no esta iniciado sesión manda llamar a log in el cual es un botón que manda llamar una función googleLogin de mi provider.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const LoggedIn();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Hubo un error'));
          } else {
            return const LogIn();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Este es mi provider que uso para la auth de Google con firebase.

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  bool isEmpty() => _user == null;

  Future googleLogin() async {
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) return;
    _user = googleUser;

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

La siguiente url es el repo donde esta alojado el código: [repo del proyecto](https://github.com/FelipeRodriguezMX/flutter_firebase_authentication)

Comment: Cuando mencionas que se te cierra el app, también se desconecta del debug mode? como lo pruebas? en modo debug o release? dispositivo físico o emulador? No te aparece ningún log?

Comment: No sino que me refiero a que cuando la autenticacion de google te abre la modal la cual te permite seleccionar el usuario con que quieres iniciar session y una vez que le das tap a la cuenta que vas a usar la modal se cierra y no hace nada.

Comment: revisaste el log? para ver que aparece? donde lo estas probando, dispositivo real o emulador? android? iOS?

Comment: estoy usando dispositivo real con Android y en mi consola no me  muestra ningún error

Comment: trata de hacer un debug en tu método googleLogin() , para que veas en que linea se queda

Comment: Hice un log antes y despues del await googleSignIn.signIn(); y solo me imprimio el log que tenia antes de este

Comment: Un truco para que puedas ver el log: Abre Android Studio, abre el proyecto o uno nuevo, lo importante es ver la pestaña de LogCat, conecta tu dispositivo y prueba el login, ahí podrás ver el Log de error, lo agregas en tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

```
Future<String?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e.message);
      // ignore: use_rethrow_when_possible
      throw e;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que hace el código y cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.